# Как вывести слова строки, состоящие из букв, не входящих ни в одно другое слово?

Tags: алгоритм, delphi, строки, pascal

Дана строка, нужно вывести из неё в консоль все слова, которые состоят из уникальных букв (т. е. таких, которых нет в других словах). Если хоть одна буква есть в разных словах, не выводятся все эти слова.

Comment: подсчитайте число вхождений букв в тексте. далее читайте по словам. и считайте вхождения в текущем слове. Если сумма буквы в слове не равна сумме в тексте, то пропускаем. Но можно и по другому подумать. например, сначала выкинуть все повторы букв в словах.

Answer (score 1):

Первое, что пришло на ум (не идеально):

- Разбить строку на массив подстрок (слова) по пробелам или другим
  символам.
- Двойной цикл for(), который будет заходить в слово (подстроку), а
  там идти посимвольно.
- Затем, в таком же двойном for() сравнивать символ из пункта 2, с
  символами в подстроках строки (приводя символы в верхний или нижний регистр).
- Как только символ найден - выходить из цикла и переходить к другому
  слову, иначе записать уникальное слово или пометить его индекс.

Чтобы избежать большой вложенности и улучшить читабельность кода, эти действия можно разнести по 2-3 функциям. К счастью Delphi/Pascal я забыл, поэтому не могу предложить код.

Comment: @БондаренкоДаниил если вам ответ помог - отметьте его как правильный.